# Are RC circuits suitable for use as power sequencers?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, resistors, integrated-circuit, power-sequencing

Are RC circuits suitable for use as power sequencers with EN pins on LDOs?

I know that there may be a problem with reverse sequence on power off, but some devices allow that on power down all power supplies must go down together or in reverse order, so cutting out power would solve power off problems related to RC circuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use RC networks on the enable pins of a lot of regulators. You need to read the specification of each to understand the threshold/trigger points because these may not be similar from one manufacturer to another.

Cutting the power can be a problem but if a reverse connected diode is placed across the resistor feeding the grounded capacitor, then discharge is fairly quick on all affected enable lines.

Comment: Thank you. I've another dubpt, in the case I don't want to use multiple LDOs becouse, for example, I've 3 same voltage power lines. But I need to have anyway a power sequence. If I add a very weak resistor like 1 to 5 ohm on each power line, can I consider this like a RC (C is bypass cap) delaying circuit? (I remember to have seen something like this)

Comment: Yes it might work but it depends on current taken by the regulator's input and whether 5 ohms might be too much. However, you can add more capacitance.